# Cannot vote to close a question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I tried to close this question: [Fly through a window into a new world / scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65416/fly-through-a-window-into-a-new-world-scene) as I've answered a similar one asked earlier ([Creating the Minecraft End Portal in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61965/creating-the-minecraft-end-portal-in-blender)). When I've pasted the link in the *Closing* window the message: ***This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer*** appeared. What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: Exactly what the error says. You cannot close a questions as a duplicate of a question which does not have an answer with at least one upvote. Luckily, your answer now has at least one upvote ;)